# Highcharts stacked bar data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

trying to figure out how to display this highcharts example with data categories of name (john, jane, joe) without changing how the data is supplied

```
$(function () 
{
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zAMCK/

Basically, I want to supply the category of data together. Is this possible? Also would like to supply multiple different fruits per person, which may be unique per person

Answer (score 0):

You can set for each value specific x category index, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zAMCK/1/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [[0, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1]]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [[1, 3], [1, 5], [1, 3]] //not supported duplicate x-values
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [[0, 1], [2, 5], [4, 1]]
        }]
```